# Firebase/Firestore not connecting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I am new to using firestore and I am trying to display my data in the console but getting a really weird warning.

[image: Error showing on the device]

[image: Error showing in the console]

Please let me know what code you would like to see.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

fbConfig.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';



var config = {
apiKey: 'AIzaSyDyF8h7SYE3iiYxt-ZAmdXxWu9Pd6cuvxo',
authDomain: 'manager-31000.firebaseapp.com',
databaseURL: 'https://manager-31000.firebaseio.com',
projectId: 'manager-31000',
storageBucket: 'manager-31000.appspot.com',
messagingSenderId: '1079074827203'
};
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }


export default firebase;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text
} from "react-native";

import firebase from '../config/fbConfig.js';


const db=firebase.firestore();
  db.collection('movies').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const values=snapshot.docs.map(flattenDoc);
      console.table(values);
    })
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
           <Text>Test App<Text>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: well, I just created a fbconfig.js file with the firebase config data in it and in my component I tried to display my collections in the console. I will just paste both those codes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message and the code that you provided I cannot see exactly what is wrong and causing this error. I am using firebase/firestore on my project but I have set it up differently.

Check out this tutorial: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/ for an elegant way to provide firebase to React using the Context API. Pick the bits where you setup firebase and provide it to React, ignore the rest as Auth is not related to your issue. Look for "Firebase Setup" in Table of Contents.

Then this tutorial: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-firestore-tutorial/ explains how to setup firestore.

Since you are new to firebase/firestore I believe that both tutorials will be very beneficial for you.

PS. For react-native there is a different package: 'react-native-firebase', details on how to install here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup . This doesn't change the way you setup firebase/firestore for React as shown on both tutorials that I shared.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will watch these tutorials and see if it helps.

Comment: Btw does 'firebase' package not work for react native?

Comment: It should work, react-native-firebase is recommended though. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/library-integrations

Comment: Hey, your tutorials really helped. Thanks a lot! Turns out i had misspelled the name of my collection which is 'Movies' instead of 'movies'. Thanks for your help.